# Abstract Algebra: Order of the elements generated by alphaBeta

Tags: abstract-algebra

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

This was a question I missed on my past midterm, the answer wrote down the explanation but I still don't quite understand it.

Question: $\alpha$ is a 3 cycle and $\beta$ is a 2 cycle (in some $S_n$) and suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint, write out the elements in the subgroup generated by $\alpha \beta$
, <$\alpha\beta$>=?

The professor explained that <$\alpha\beta$> = $\alpha\beta$, $(\alpha\beta)^2$, $(\alpha\beta)^3$...

I don't understand why $\alpha$ and $\beta$ start to cancel out based on their exponents:

For instance, he wrote: $(\alpha)^2 (\beta)^2 = \alpha^2$, but why does $\beta$ cancel out?

Comment: Without loss of generality, ypu can take $\alpha =(1\,2\,3)$ and $\beta=(4\,5)$ and just calculate $\alpha\beta $ and its powers explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\beta$ is a $2$-cycle, so $\beta^2=e$, where $e$ is the identity. Then $\alpha^2 e=\alpha^2$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint, they commute with each other. (For an illustrative example, imagine $\alpha=(1 2 3)$ and $\beta=(4 5)$. Then $(\alpha\beta)^2=\alpha^2$, as you can see directly, and this has nothing to do with the particular choices of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that I've made.) So you get $(\alpha\beta)^n=\alpha^n\beta^n$, and $\langle \alpha\beta\rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $6$.